# PHPExcel autoload with symfony 2.3.8

Tags: php, symfony, phpexcel, autoload

I have an issue in using PHPExcel with symfony 2.3.8, I have installed phpexcel through the following composer edit

```
"require": {
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "*"
}
```

Then in the command prompt I have navigated to the folder where my composer.json and executed the command composer update, it updates everything related to phpexcel in the vendor folder

```
vendor\
      phpoffice\
              phpexcel\Classes\
                       PHPExcel\
                       PHPExcel.php
```

My autoload_namespaces.php in vendor\composer\ looks like

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
     .....
     'PHPExcel' => array($vendorDir . '/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes'),
     .....
);
```

and in my controller I have used that library by using "use PHPExcel",

when I use the PHPExcel_Style_Alignment class it gives class not found error, If I give

```
use PHPExcel_Style_Alignment;
```

in the top of controller, it works fine..!, the same thing is happened to all other classes like PHPExcel_IOFactory etc..

Whether I need to include all classes of phpexcel with the use keyword? but which is a bad practice,

What I have to do to load all classes of phpexcel library automatically when needed?

Comment: This is a misunderstanding. `use PHPExcel` doesn't technically *"import"* the whole library. It's creating a "shortcut" or an alias of the class for the given file. See [namespaces](http://fr2.php.net/language.namespaces.importing.php). In order to use it, you may just use `new \PHPExcel_IOFactory` which will work just fine, without any `use` statement

Comment: I have used the backslash, and it is just working fine, Yes, I misunderstood the namespace concept